# Hyper-V - RDP into guest that is VPN'ed into inaccesible network (or set custom resolution in VM Connection)

Tags: windows-8, remote-desktop, vpn, hyper-v

I have a local Win8 Hyper-V guest running XP that I use to VPN into a network that is completely isolated from the internet. The guest and the host share the same network adapter through a "external network" virtual switch on the host.

From what I understand, once the guest logs into the VPN, it becomes isolated from the local network, including the host. This is preventing me from establishing an RDP connection to the guest once it has connected to the VPN, leaving me with the clunky Virtual Machine Connection as my only alternative to connecting to the guest. RDP works fine when the guest isn't connected to the VPN.

So my question is, is there any way to still use RDP in this kind of situation? And if not, is there a way to make Virtual Machine Connection more usable by being able to pick any arbitrary display resolution? There's a small list of resolutions you can pick from in Display Settings when using VM Connection and none of them match my display's native resolution, which makes it annoying to use.

Comment: What about going into settings in Hyper-V for that VM and clicking Add Hardware, network card? See if you can add a second network card to the same (external) network, then try connecting to the second assigned IP via RDP after you connect via VPN.

Comment: I'm dealing with the same issue as IvanG...I've installed a second network adapter but neither are accessible from the host (my physical machine)

Comment: @bill-anton Yeah, I got the impression that the VPN software is intentionally trying to prevent what we're trying to accomplish since, at least in my case, the security offered by locking out all other connections is the whole reason the VPN is being used in the first place. Trying to circumnavigate that started to feel like asking for trouble so what I did instead was replace Hyper-V with vmware, which has a much much more useful native display mode (equivalent of VM Connection)